# ODE with conditions within the interval

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Can anyone please recommend some publications related to ODEs with non-initial, non-boundary conditions, but conditions for points inside the interval, on which the ODE is defined?

Comment: The monograph _Non-Self-Adjoin Eigenvalue Problems_ (Elsevier, 2003) by Mennicken & Möller considers throughout the whole book very general ODE conditions that include both boundary and interior points. So it seems like a standard idea in their area. Perusing the book's bibliography might lead you to the right corner of the literature.

Answer (score 2):

The key phrase here seems to be "nonlocal boundary conditions". A survey of differential equations with such conditions was given [here](https://www.emis.de/journals/AMEN/2007/070907-5.pdf), with 127 further references. In particular, see conditions (13), (18), and (23) in this survey.